How to migrate GraphQL.net 2.4 to 7.8
I have to upgrade the version of pachage GraphQL from 2.4 to the last version 7.8.
Everything goes fine until I have error on the schema :
public QAPortalSchema(IDependencyResolver resolver) : base(resolver)
{
    Query = resolver.Resolve<QAPortalQuery>();
    Mutation = resolver.Resolve<QAPortalMutation>();
}

I replace the IDependencyResolver by IServiceProvider and the define Query and Mutation like this :
public QAPortalSchema(IServiceProvider serviceProvider) : base(serviceProvider)
{
    Query = new AutoRegisteringObjectGraphType<QAPortalQuery>();
    Mutation = new AutoRegisteringObjectGraphType<QAPortalMutation>();
}

I have the following error with the changes :
The type 'QAPortalQuery' cannot be used as type parameter 'TSourceType' in the generic type or method 'AutoRegisteringObjectGraphType<TSourceType>'. The type 'QAPortalQuery' must NOT be convertible to 'IGraphType'

There is the version of the QAPOrtalQuery which works with 2.4 version :
public class QAPortalQuery : ObjectGraphType<object>
{

    public QAPortalQuery()
    {
        Field<NonConformityGroupType>(GraphQLGroupsConstants.NON_CONFORMITY, 
            resolve: context => new { });
        Field<QualityAssuranceGroupType>(GraphQLGroupsConstants.NON_CONFORMITY_QA,
            resolve: context => new { });
        Field<DepartmentManagerGroupType>(GraphQLGroupsConstants.NON_CONFORMITY_RESP_DEPT, resolve: context => new { });
        Field<TreatmentManagerGroupType>(GraphQLGroupsConstants.NON_CONFORMITY_RESP_TREAT, resolve: context => new { });
        Field<ImpactAnalysisGroupType>(GraphQLGroupsConstants.NON_CONFORMITY_IMPACT_ANALYSIS, resolve: context => new { });
        Field<ClosingGroupType>(GraphQLGroupsConstants.NON_CONFORMITY_CLOSING_AQ,resolve: context => new { });
        Field<ImprovementActionGroupType>(GraphQLGroupsConstants.IMPROVEMENT_ACTION, resolve: context => new { });
        Field<CustomerSatisfactionGroupType>(GraphQLGroupsConstants.CUSTOMER_SATISFACTION, resolve: context => new { });
        Field<ReportingGroupType>(GraphQLGroupsConstants.REPORTING, resolve: context => new { });
        Field<EmployeeGroupType>(GraphQLGroupsConstants.EMPLOYEE, resolve: context => new { });
        Field<ProjectGroupType>(GraphQLGroupsConstants.PROJECT, resolve: context => new { });
        Field<AuthorizationGroupType>(GraphQLGroupsConstants.AUTHORIZATION, resolve: context => new { });
        Field<AuditTrailGroupType>(GraphQLGroupsConstants.AUDIT_TRAIL, resolve: context => new { });
        Field<NotificationGroupType>(GraphQLGroupsConstants.NOTIFICATION, resolve: context => new { });
        Field<AuditGroupType>(GraphQLGroupsConstants.AUDIT, resolve: context => new { });

    }

}

I searched a lot on the documentation of GraphQL.Net but migrate from 2.4 to 7.8 is a bit shaky and it's hard for me to found solutions
Thank's for your help !
